# Overlapping cohorts comparison in dashboard

Tags: powerbi

Making a dashboard that will compare 1 cohort to another. So that the performance of a group can be compared to the other but the selection of group will occur in the dashboard by the end user and could have shared items. My plan is to Union the data, add a column with cohort 1 or 2 for grouping and then have the item name or null in two filter columns so each cohort. Is there a better clearer way to do this? Building in power bi

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to have 2 sets of Slicers and visuals on a report page.  Using the Interactions feature you can set the Cohort 1 Slicers to only affect the Cohort 1 visuals and vice-versa.

Here's the doco on the Interactions feature:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-reports-visual-interactions

For the equivalent in PBI Desktop, on the **Report** view, select a visual (e.g. a Slicer) and then go to the **Visual Tools / Format** ribbon and click **Edit Interactions**.